# Angular - Modify controller variables within $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to modify my controller's variables from within a call to $http (which receives data from an API). These controller variables are bound in my view with ng-model.

However, it's not working -- nothing is displaying!

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', ContactController]);

function ContactController($scope, $http) {

    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';

    $http.get('../server/getdata').success(function(data) {
        // I would like to set the firstName and lastName variables 
        // from the above parent scope into here. Is this possible? 
        this.firstName = data.firstName;
        this.lastName = data.lastName;
    });
}
```

Any thoughts here??

Answer (score 1):

Just need to preserve the value of `this` at the time the capture is created by assigning it to another variable such as `self`

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', ContactController]);

function ContactController($scope, $http) {

    var self = this;

    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';

    $http.get('../server/getdata').success(function(data) {
        // I would like to set the firstName and lastName variables 
        // from the above parent scope into here. Is this possible? 
        self.firstName = data.firstName;
        self.lastName = data.lastName;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JC! This is similar to Phil's response as well. However, are you able to comment why (if) these approaches are preferred to using $scope? I've seen $scope used in online examples, while I was researching for ways to get this to work

Comment: Using `$scope` is just another way of saving a reference to the controller. The real problem is the variable `this`. It refers to the controller when the controller is being instantiated, but it changes to a different object when the `$http` callback is executed so you need another way of referring to the controller within that callback. If the controller is attached to `$scope` for instance as member named `ctrl` you can just reference it there like so: `$scope.ctrl.firstName`. However, in my opinion that's less clear than explicitly saving the reference in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `this` in the `$http` callback is no longer your controller.

Assign the `this` value to a scoped variable, eg

```
var ctrl = this;

ctrl.firstName = '';
ctrl.lastName = '';

// keep in mind the "success" and "error" methods on the $http promise
// have been deprecated. Use the standard "then" method instead.
$http.get('../server/getdata').then(function(response) {
    ctrl.firstName = response.data.firstName;
    ctrl.lastName = response.data.lastName;
});
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice regarding the deprecated `$http` callback methods.

Comment: Thanks @Phil. This worked; also thanks for the heads up to start using "then" instead of "success"!

Comment: @Ricky some reading is available here ~ http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Answer (score -1):

Change this to $scope in success function so your code will be like

```
$scope.firstName = data.firstName;
$scope.lastName = data.lastName;
```

this inside success function has function scope not global scope so this does not bind to controller.

Comment: Presumably OP is using a *"controller-as"* expression and as such, suggesting they use `$scope` is not applicable.

Comment: @Phil: I've seen some examples online of using this "$scope" object in the manner described by Sarjan, here. What is the difference between using this $scope and using var self = this, for example? (and then referencing "self" in the inner function)